# How to defer parsing the jQuery code file?

Tags: jquery, shopify, jquery-deferred, timber

I need to defer this code in my Shopify `theme.liquid`

```
 {{ 'jquery.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag | remove: ' type="text/javascript"' }}
```

Can anyone help how to do this? It's in the `<head>`.

I've tried using different techniques like

```
<script src="{{ 'jquery.min.js' | asset_url  }}" defer></script>

  {%- include "include_css" -%}
 {{ 'jquery.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag | remove: ' type="text/javascript"' }}

  <!-- Header hook for plugins ================================================== -->
  {{ content_for_header }}
  <!-- /Header hook for plugins ================================================== -->
```

When I do defer it doesn't show some pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question

Deferring jQuery is often a big task (but also often worth it!) - there's often a lot of inline code in themes that rely on jQuery being there, so it's likely that your image code is relying on a jQuery that now isn't loaded at the time the inline script runs.

This is the correct syntax:
`<script src="{{ 'jquery.min.js' | asset_url  }}" defer></script>`

But if you still have the original `| script tag` line in your theme, you will be loading jQuery twice and increasing your page's overhead rather than decreasing it like you intend.  What's probably happening in this instance is that jQuery loads, some plugins for jQuery get loaded into the not-deferred version of jQuery, then your deferred version loads and overwrites the first version and blows out all of the loaded plugins.

First, you'll need to make sure you're only loading one version of the asset. Next, make sure any jQuery plugins and jQuery-dependant assets are also deferred. Finally, you will need to go through your theme to clean up any inline scripts to make sure you're deferring anything that expects a preloaded jQuery.

Open your browser's console and look for any errors relating to jQuery.  You will then need to go into your theme files and defer those scripts to run after jQuery is up and running.

Unfortunately, you can't simply put the keyword `defer` on an inline script tag - it only applies to scripts that have a `src` specified. Still, there are a few possible ways you can get around this:

- You can move the inline scripts to an external script tag, which *can* have the `defer` attribute.  Note however that asset files do not have access to most Liquid variables, as the asset needs to be cacheable.  You can access things like translations, but you cannot access anything that might change depending on the user or the page - this includes the cart, products, collections, and even the shop variable.
- You can write a small helper function to wait for dependencies to load, which would take a parameter name and a function. If the dependency is in the global scope you can run the function, otherwise use a `setTimeout` and try again in a few hundred milliseconds.
- Wrapping the inline function with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' function(){ /* inline code */ })` should also work - the `defer`'d jQuery, being higher in the DOM, would run on `DOMContentLoaded` as well but would be first in line, so when your function gets its turn your jQuery variable will be defined.

Good luck!